# D3- multiple radial progress charts

Tags: javascript, loops, d3.js, charts

I'm new to D3 and am trying to create multiple radial progress charts. I have a single one working but am not sure how to loop through this in D3 to make the second one show up.

The code that I'm using is adapted from a JS Fiddle I found that uses data attributes to populate the graph.

The text is appearing as it is just a `<p>` tag but using D3, but I can't get the graph to go along with it. I've been troubleshooting different ways to implement this but can't find any good documentation or Stack Overflow answers that will help me do what I need.

Thanks!

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.progress')[0];
var start = 0;
var end = parseFloat(wrapper.dataset.percentage);

var colors = {
fill: '#2c3187',
track: '#cec6bc',
text: '#2c3187',
stroke: '#FFFFFF',
}

var endAngle = Math.PI * 2;
var formatText = d3.format('.0%');
var boxSize = 200;
var count = end;
var progress = start;
var step = end < start ? -0.01 : 0.01;

//Define the circle
var circle = d3.svg.arc()
.startAngle(0)
.innerRadius(100)
.outerRadius(60);

//setup SVG wrapper
var svg = d3.select(wrapper)
.append('svg')
.attr('width', boxSize)
.attr('height', boxSize);

// Add Group container
var g = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + boxSize / 2 + ',' + boxSize / 2 + ')');

//Setup track
var track = g.append('g');
track.append('path')
  .attr('fill', colors.track)
  .attr('stroke', colors.stroke)
  .attr('stroke-width', 7 + 'px')
  .attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle));

//Add colour fill
var value = track.append('path')
  .attr('class', 'radial-path')
  .attr('fill', colors.fill)
  .attr('stroke', colors.stroke)
  .attr('stroke-width', 7 + 'px');

//Add text value
  var numberText = track.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'radial-text')
  .attr('fill', colors.text)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('dy', '.8rem');

//Action
function update(progress) {
  //update position of endAngle
  value.attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle * progress));
  //update text value
  numberText.text(formatText(progress));
}

(function iterate() {
  //call update to begin animation
  update(progress);
  if (count > 0) {
    //reduce count till it reaches 0
    count--;
    //increase progress
    progress += step;
    //Control the speed of the fill
    setTimeout(iterate, 10);
  }
    })();
```

```html
<div class="progress" data-percentage="35"></div>
<p class="radial-text">Chart One</p>

<div class="progress" data-percentage="60"></div>
<p class="radial-text">Chart Two</p>
  
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the `document.querySelectorAll('.progress')[0];` portion with a variable instead of a static integer, for example

```
var nextChart = 0;
var wrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.progress')[nextChart];
```

and then have it increment at the end of the page and wrap all code in a function and go through it again.

```
nextChart++
```

Posted a working version here: [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CeImmw1aYhCt9fsKMMSK?p=preview)

This is not a very good solution but it should give you an idea of how it could be done.

Comment: Solutions is simple enough for a d3 noob to understand! Thanks!